# Check if the current SharePoint Page is in Edit mode from within a SharePoint Online App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a SharePoint hosted app. I need to enable an **edit section** inside the app only when the page is in edit mode. This way I am making sure that only users with edit permission can view this option. The issue is that I am not able to determine, from within the app, whether or not the page is in the edit mode.

Currently, I am passing the following in the src of the ClientWebPart to check if the Web Part is in the edit mode,

```
editmode=_editMode_
```

Though, this implementation is working, it includes the following steps:

1. Click the **Edit Page** option of the SharePoint page.
2. In edit mode, for the target Web Part, click the **Edit Web Part** option.
3. The private **edit section** is now visible.

My question is, can I reduce the above number of steps by completing bypassing the second option? Please advice.

Comment: AFAIK there is a css option for edit mode. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760477/sharepoint-custom-style-for-page-in-edit-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no direct way through which the SharePoint app can communicate directly with the host page. We have to rely on the limited queryStrings that SharePoint provides on-load. Which means that, the user has to first edit the page and then, edit the web part and only then, I can pick up the info that the given app is in the edit mode. One extra step for the user.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeapps/en-US/091559b6-eb8c-467b-bcbd-d3fef3415772/check-if-the-current-sharepoint-page-is-in-edit-mode-from-within-a-sharepoint-online-app?forum=appsforsharepoint

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of WSSDesignConsole placeholder from the master page

Comment: Can I access that from the app? As far as I know, the app code will be executed from within a frame and since, the domain of the page will be different than the domain of the app, browsers will block all the cross-domain access for security.

Comment: Is your master page hosted under site collection level and using the master page, you can, although its web level

Comment: In SharePoint Online I have absolutely no access on the page where the app is hosted. I can't even get the url of the page where the app is running. So any tag, which is a part of the host page and not app page is invisible to the app.